# Will entangeld particles stay entangled?

Tags: quantum-spin, quantum-entanglement

I want to consider an experiment:
We create two entangled particles a and b such that the spin of each is opposite to the other.
We then measure spin in z direction (1). So we get a is up and b is down or the other way around.
Then we measure spin in x direction (2), which doesn't commute, so it somehow shuffles the cards for z.
Finally the spin in z is measured again (3). 
Are the particles still entangled? Can I be sure that their spins are still complementary or is there a chance that now a and b both point in the same direction?

I am looking forward to answers :)

This question is close to the other question, but I still wonder what predictions this makes to my proposed thought experiment. Can't this be answered by a simple "yes, spins are still complementary, because..." or "no, spins don't have to be complementary anymore, because...?". Or is my question somehow not valid?

Comment: Assuming the particles were initially entangled in a state with their spin along z axis pointing in opposite directions, the first measurement (1) of spin along z direction forces them to collapse into a non entangled state. After that you can do the usual thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does measuring the location of one entangled photon affect its pair?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/454898/how-does-measuring-the-location-of-one-entangled-photon-affect-its-pair)

Comment: @M111: What do you mean by "do the usual thing"? Are there now 2 wavefunctions, one for each particle, evolving completely seperately such that it's totally possible to measure both up at (3)?